# Backup Restore, CPU usage and Extended Events

Tags: backup, sql-server-2017, extended-events, azure-vm, cpu

I'm working on measuring the performance impact of Backups on CPU. I would like to capture all the backup operations and CPU usage. I'm running a weekly full backup, daily diff, and 15 min log backup. Are there any options in Extended Events we can use to capture CPU usage?

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [Backup_Events_Trace] ON SERVER ADD EVENT sqlserver.backup_restore_progress_trace (ACTION(sqlserver.client_hostname, sqlserver.database_name))
    ,ADD EVENT sqlserver.databases_backup_restore_throughput (ACTION(sqlserver.client_hostname, sqlserver.database_name)) ADD TARGET package0.event_file (SET filename = N'L:\XE\Backup_Events_Trace.xel')
    WITH (STARTUP_STATE = OFF)
GO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch CPU utilisation by adding this event:

`sqlos.scheduler_monitor_system_health_ring_buffer_recorded`

Adding this to your Extended Events session will return CPU utilisation statistics (among others).

When you query the data, there are two fields - `process_utilization` and `system_idle` which represents the SQL process CPU utilisation and the idle CPU % respectively. By subtracting `process_utilization` from `system_idle` you get the non-SQL used CPU from the server.

Answer (score 0):

In addition as far as I know you might get the CPU usage from the inbuilt system health extended events as well.

It keeps a track of the CPU metrics along with queries ran. You may want to tweak as needed if interested. Else you can always go for other events or pulling data from cache using DMVs if possible